# How to insert html in a child component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to insert html into a child component. Basically something like this:

`<custom-container><p>Parnet content</p></custom-container>`

I can find references for passing data to child component but not able to find how to pass actual html inside my selector?

Answer (score 21):

You can also use `<ng-content>` with `select` attribute

**Parent Component:**

```
<child-component>
    <div sample>Content form parent</div>
</child-component>
```

**Child Component:**

```
something..
<ng-content select="[sample]"></ng-content>
some more...
```

**Output:**

```
something..
<div>Content from parent</div>
some more...
```

More details [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content)

Answer (score 1):

ng-content tag can be used in the template of the child component. That tag will take in anything that you put in between your component selector.